# PHP doesn't compile when there is a space before array creation

Tags: php, arrays

So I just spent 30 minutes trying to debug my code, when I finally understood that:

```
$words = array("word", "word", "word"); // doesn't compile
$words =array("word", "word", "word"); // Does compile
```

I just tried deleting the space between "=" and "array" as a sort of desperate random try and it worked. Is it a normal behaviour from PHP, considering usually the "=" instruction is totally fine with spaces?

Comment: PHP works just fine with that space after `=`. See here: http://3v4l.org/0CBtX. You have something else going on.

Comment: The space isn't the issue here.  What did the error you got say?  Because chances are the character you deleted wasn't a space.  It was probably some unicode character that just rendered like that.

Comment: I've seen things like this on every place and almost always it is about the user copy and paste the code from another place with some other encoding different from his own and when paste it, it came with  some char that don't appear on the editor.

Comment: @RocketHazmat almost at the same time, same thought.

Comment: I just tried deleting and putting back the space in place, and the color in my editor was different. Then it worked. So yes it was probably a special character. That's strange though because I didn't copypaste that code... Thanks anyway

Comment: @Malharhak PHP actually nevers "compiles" (note not assuming bcomplier, Xcache or APC plugins what can compile PHP to bytecode like but the defualt PHP engine) but interpret the .php files.. C, C++ and Java as examples needs to be compiled

Comment: Exact. But it does a syntax validation before executing the script, this is what I called compile (it doesn't do anything until that step is successful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was some sort of special character that looks exactly like a space but wasn't one. Putting back a normal space worked.